# Data Extraction in R using regex

Tags: r, regex, ocr, tesseract

```
Country Risk: H O/M&/LO
Region’: Y'O / N®
Jurisdiction: Y'O / N
```

I need to extract the value with which O is not associated. In first case, I want M, in second case I want N, and in third case I want to assign N to the corresponding variable. I am using regex, but every time it takes the complete value. I want the value with which O is not associated.

Answer (score 0):

Use `gmi` regex modifiers with the following regex pattern:

```
\/(?=[^\/O]*(?:\/|$))[^A-Z]*\K[A-Z]+
```

https://regex101.com/r/estcbg/1